# Rest API for Blockchain.info

Tags: c#, rest, blockchain.info-api

I am working with asp.net and i am accessing blockchain.info api for getting the bitcoin current rate  and i was using the flowing method for getting the same

```
public string BtcToDollar(decimal btc)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://blockchain.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
           new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        string methodename = "frombtc?currency=USD&value=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(btc * 100000000) ;
        var response = client.GetAsync(methodename);
        return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

     }
```

this was working fine but now I am getting erorr

Server Error in '/' Application.
The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

Stack Trace:

[WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.]
   System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +606
   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar) +64

[HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.]

[AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.]
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) +4324957
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification) +12846467
   System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result() +33

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead

```
public string BtcToDollar(decimal btc)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolTypeExtensions.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolTypeExtensions.Tls12;
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://blockchain.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        string methodename = "frombtc?currency=USD&value=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(btc * 100000000);
        var response = client.GetAsync(methodename);
       return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is literally telling you the problem...

> Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel

Meaning you're not using `HTTPS` scheme.

```
public string BtcToDollar(decimal btc)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://blockchain.com/");
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        string methodename = "frombtc?currency=USD&value=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(btc * 100000000);
        var response = client.GetAsync(methodename);
        return response.Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

Try that! ^ (also wrapped client in using statement, as you're currently not disposing of it)

Comment: but i am using SSL certificate

Comment: No you are not. Your URL starts with HTTP... you need HTTPS

Comment: I am using https still have the same issue